# How to pass additional info needed for the authorzation using HTTP Basic Auth?

Tags: http, authentication, soap, http-headers, basic-authentication

I'm writing a SOAP service with a basic authentication. To decide, whether the consumer may access a resource, I analyze his credentials. But I also need some additional information: The firm the user (as person) belongs to.

A user can belong to multiple firms. So he can e.g. access documents like `my_document_xyz_a` when logging in as an employee of the firm `firm_A` and documents like `my_document_xyz_b` when logging in as an employee of the firm `firm_B`.

So I / my SOAP server need/-s the credentials (`username` and `password`) and the firm name (or token).

**Which HTTP header is appropriate for this purpose? Or should I use a custom header HTTP header?**

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add a security section in your SOAP method schema to pass the user role.

But if you really want it in the header (because your code is already parsing HTTP headers to obtain the authentication info) then use a cookie.